# Completing transcription of 1668 Baptism record of Maria Eva Wittwer from Sindolsheim

Tags: church-records, german-language, transcriptions, kurrent, german

I have the baptism record for one of my 7x great-grandmothers, Maria Eva Wittwer of Sindolsheim, in 1668.

Can you help me to complete the transcription, as parts are difficult to read?

[image]

```
15. Annus MDCLXVIII.
Januarius.
Hanß Wittwers, burgers und schwartzfärbers allhier, und Margaretha, seiner
Haußfr. eheliche tochter, war den 9 d. [frühe?] gegen tag [?] tagesliecht [?]
[?] zur hl. tauff getragen, und [?], von Anna Maria, [?]
[?] allhier Haußfr. [?] Kaufmanns, bürgers allhier
[?] von Barbara, [Wenzel?] [?], bürgers und [Wirths?] allhier ehel. tochter.
                                den 10. Jan.
```